# symfony ldap always redirect to login page

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I have symfony website. This is my login form. Let's say that I have entered username, password, security code. My problem is everytime I click the login button, it always redirect to login page as the image below despite my data is right or wrong. And to the worst, no error displayed when I submit the wrong data. I have tried to clear the cache and update my composer. But none of it works. This is my login controller

```
public function loginAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $session = $this->get('session');
    $session->set('login_referer', $request->server->get('HTTP_REFERER'));

    if ($session->has(AuthenticationConstant::AUTHENTICATION_ATTEMPTS_EXCEEDED)) {
        $error = $session->get(AuthenticationConstant::AUTHENTICATION_ATTEMPTS_EXCEEDED);        
    } else if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)){
        $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    } else {
        $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    }

    // remove session error message because if not remove, the error will saved in session 
    //so even there's no error, it stills display an error
    $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    $session->remove(AuthenticationConstant::AUTHENTICATION_ATTEMPTS_EXCEEDED);

    return $this->render('AcmeGlobalBundle:Security:login.html.twig' , array(
            'last_username' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
            'error'         => $error,
            'token'         => $this->generateToken(),
            'captcha'       => $this->get('mikroskil_captcha'), 
        )
    );
}
```

[image: login page]

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer. Just change the permission in your session file. My session was located in `app/sessions/`. So I change the permission by run this command `sudo chmod -R 777 app/sessions/`. But first, you must take a look at your `error.log`